# Запись данных в Excel файл

Tags: python, excel, csv

Мне необходимо, чтобы программа записывала полученные данные в таблицу. Я использую модуль `csv`. Запись в таблицу происходит, но без разделения на столбцы, а сплошным текстом. Если установить вручную параметр `"Текст по столбцам"` все преобразуется в желаемый результат.

Можно ли как-то установить нужный параметр по умолчанию, или же решить проблему в коде?

[image]

Вот два основных фрагмента, относительно записи в CSV:

```
def write_csv(data):
with open("Amz.csv", "a") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow((data["title"],
                     data["price"],
                     data["rating"],
                     data["brand"],
                     data["sellers"],
                     data["link"]))

data = {"title": title,
                        "price": full_price,
                        "rating": rating,
                        "brand": brand,
                        "sellers": res[0],
                        "link": link}
                write_csv(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(r'/path/to/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

чтобы записать Pandas.DataFrame в CSV файл:

```
df.to_csv(r'/path/to/result.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```